# Why do I receive different results in an Access query when the order of the columns is different with a distinct clause?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Exactly as the title says.

I have an MS Access database. I didn't create it, I was handed it with a request to update a query. My task was to add a column with a calculated result, and we added a new column... essentially lets say we have query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c 
FROM tbl1
```

Modified with a UDF to be:

```
SELECT UDF(d) as e, * 
INTO tb2 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, d FROM tbl1)
```

We did this, and got different answers, 3 more rows out of hundreds of thousands. I assumed simply that column d must contain more information and after removing duplicates by the DISTINCT clause we ended up with more columns.

In attempting to verify this, we discovered that the order of the columns seemed to matter. If we did this:

```
SELECT UDF(d) as e, * 
INTO tb2 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a, c, b, d FROM tbl1)
```

The extra columns went away.

I thought at first that I was using distinct wrong, but checking different syntax combinations resulted in errors, and looking up the SQL documentation for access said that this was correct. A colleague suggested that we needed a GROUP BY clause but since we're not doing any aggregation and we want the globally unique records that doesn't seem to fit.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your second and third query should give you the same results, but the first one is clearly different since you are using `DISTINCT` over 3 columns

Comment: I should edit it for clarity but I can't seem to at the moment. I did get extra results from a,b,c to a,b,c,d (as expected) but in trying to prove it to the other team I got different results between a,b,c,d and a,b,d,c. The second bit is what I want to learn about.

Comment: I suggest you remove everything from the question that isn't relevant to the actual problem. The first query, the UDF, the SELECT INTO.

Comment: So `SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, d FROM tbl1` gives a different number of rows than `SELECT DISTINCT a, c, b, d FROM tbl1` ? What are the data types of the columns a,b,c,d?

Comment: @Andre I did the steps in your first comment, removing everything prior to setting up this question. The effect remained. Now the type of the columns might be an issue... I was expecting them to be text fields, but they're memo fields.